# Copy records from one field to another field automatically in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I want to update my contact object field - phone from the User object field -phone automatically. How to achieve this in Salesforce? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use process builder, on update of User, update the phone of the linked contact.